# How to design systemd path unit?

Tags: systemd

Program `my_prog` is to be launched after boot. It creates a Unix domain socket `/tmp/my_prog.sock` owned by `root:root`.

I am trying to do the followings:

- Change the owner of the socket file to `www-data:www-data` after it is created.
- Delete the socket file after the program exits.

This is my first version of unit file `my_prog.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Program
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/my_prog
ExecStartPost=chmod www-data:www-data /tmp/my_prog.sock
ExecStopPost=rm -f /tmp/my_prog.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This version has two problems:

- The owner of `/tmp/my_prog.sock` is never changed - always `root:root`.
- `/tmp/my_prog.sock` is never removed after this service is stopped.

I guess it is commands `chmod` and `rm` getting executed too soon that gives me such unexpected results:

- `chmod` runs before `my_prog` finishes creating the socket file, and
- `rm` runs before `my_program` exits (`my_program` prohibits its socket file from being deleted when it is running?).

What follow are my second version, which fails to give me correct results, either:

file `my_prog.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Program
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/my_prog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

file `my_prog-socket.path`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My program - notify socket existence

[Path]
PathExists=/tmp/my_prog.sock
```

file `my_prog-socket.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My program - change owner and remove socket

[Service]
ExecStart=chown www-data:www-data /tmp/my_prog.sock
ExecStopPost=rm -f /tmp/my_prog.sock
```

I have run out of all tricks.
What's wrong with my unit files?
Is there more elegant design than above?

Thanks!

P.S.: For those who are interested, this legacy version `/etc/init.d/my-prog` works as expected, at least:

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:         my-program
# Default-Start:    2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:     0 1 6
# Short-Description:    My Program
# Description:      My Program
### END INIT INFO


PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/local/bin/my_prog
NAME=my-program
DESC="My Program"
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
PIDFILE=/var/run/my-prog.pid
SOCKET_FILE="/tmp/my-prog.sock"

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

grant_socket_access()
{
    #Wait program to create socket.
    count=1
    while [ "$count" -lt "50" ]
    do
        if [ -S $SOCKET_FILE ]
        then
            chown www-data:www-data $SOCKET_FILE
            return 0
        fi
        sleep 0.2
        count=`expr $count + 1`
    done
    echo >&2 "$NAME fails to grant access to Unix socket file: $SOCKET_FILE"
    return 1
}

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

case "$1" in
    start)
        log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" $NAME
        rm -f $SOCKET_FILE
        if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON -b -m
        then
            grant_socket_access
        else
            rm -f $SOCKET_FILE
        fi
        log_end_msg $?
        ;;
    stop)
        log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" $NAME
        rm -f $SOCKET_FILE
        if start-stop-daemon --stop --retry TERM/10/KILL/5 --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON --remove-pidfile
        then
            log_daemon_msg "$DESC" "$NAME stopped"
            log_end_msg 0
        else
            log_end_msg 1
        fi
        ;;
    reload|force-reload)
        log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" $NAME
        rm -f $SOCKET_FILE
        if start-stop-daemon --stop --signal HUP --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE --exec $DAEMON
        then
            grant_socket_access
            log_end_msg $?
        else
            log_end_msg 1
        fi
        ;;
    restart)
        log_daemon_msg "Restarting $DESC" $NAME
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
    status)
        status_of_proc -p "$PIDFILE" "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|restart|reload|force-reload|status}" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

**Edit**

Following the recipe kindly provided by @Mark Stosberg, I have modified my original first version to have `/bin/chown` and `/bin/rm` just now.

I get the desired result from line `ExecStopPost=/bin/rm -f /tmp/my_prog.sock` in the new version. However, `ExecStart=/bin/chown www-data:www-data /tmp/my_prog.sock` outputs this error:

```
chown[8388]: /bin/chown: connot access '/tmp/my_prog.socket'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your script through your `systemd-analyze verify ./your-file.service` reveals the problems:

```
[/home/mark/tmp/t.service:7] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: chmod www-data:www-data /tmp/my_prog.sock                                   
[/home/mark/tmp/t.service:8] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: rm -f /tmp/my_prog.sock
```

The documentation in `man systemd.service` documents the requirement that the executable paths must be absolute.

---

Your error refers to a file with a `.socket` extension, but your example shows a `.sock` extension. Confirm that you are using `.sock` or `.socket` consistently everywhere.

---

If your service doesn't need to run as root, you can improve the security and avoid the need to `chown`, by using the `User=` and `Group=` directives to run the service as a different user. This will create a socket owned by that user instead of root.

Comment: Thanks!  Absolute executable path solves my second problem.  My first problem remains.

Comment: `.socket` is a typo during redaction.  `User=` and `Group=` fix my problem and I think it is the most elegant design. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks! Absolute executable path solves my second problem. My first problem remains

Your first problem is that chmod doesn't take "owner:group", you really want 'chown'

Ex:

```
ExecStartPost=**chown** www-data:www-data /tmp/my_prog.sock
```